# Error 500--Internal Server Error - ADF

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

### When i run the JDeveloper and use ADF framework to create a web application, i create a business components and use the data control to drag and drop table from database, but when i run the application the web-logic give me this error (Error 500--Internal Server Error), i will give you the full error and i need your help to solve it.

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error

oracle.jbo.JboException: JBO-29114 ADFContext is not setup to process messages for this exception. Use the exception stack trace and error code to investigate the root cause of this exception. Root cause error code is JBO-29112. Error message parameters are {0=GMT+02:00}
at oracle.jbo.server.OracleSQLBuilderImpl.setSessionTimeZone(OracleSQLBuilderImpl.java:5540)
at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl.refreshConnectionMetadata(DBTransactionImpl.java:5329)
at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl.initTransaction(DBTransactionImpl.java:1167)
at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl.initTxn(DBTransactionImpl.java:6838)
at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl2.connectToDataSource(DBTransactionImpl2.java:298)
at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl2.connectToDataSource(DBTransactionImpl2.java:329)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.DefaultConnectionStrategy.connect(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:203)
at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationPoolMessageHandler.doPoolConnect(ApplicationPoolMessageHandler.java:600)
at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationPoolMessageHandler.doPoolMessage(ApplicationPoolMessageHandler.java:417)
at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationModuleImpl.doPoolMessage(ApplicationModuleImpl.java:9053)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.sendPoolMessage(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:4606)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.prepareApplicationModule(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:2536)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.doCheckout(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:2346)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.useApplicationModule(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:3245)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.SessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(SessionCookieImpl.java:571)
at oracle.jbo.http.HttpSessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(HttpSessionCookieImpl.java:234)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.SessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(SessionCookieImpl.java:504)
at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.SessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(SessionCookieImpl.java:499)
at oracle.adf.model.bc4j.DCJboDataControl.initializeApplicationModule(DCJboDataControl.java:517)
at oracle.adf.model.bc4j.DCJboDataControl.getApplicationModule(DCJboDataControl.java:867)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCDataControl.setErrorHandler(DCDataControl.java:487)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUApplication.setErrorHandler(JUApplication.java:261)
at oracle.adf.model.BindingContext.put(BindingContext.java:1318)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCDataControlReference.getDataControl(DCDataControlReference.java:247)
at oracle.adf.model.BindingContext.instantiateDataControl(BindingContext.java:1020)
at oracle.adf.model.dcframe.DataControlFrameImpl.doFindDataControl(DataControlFrameImpl.java:1645)
at oracle.adf.model.dcframe.DataControlFrameImpl.internalFindDataControl(DataControlFrameImpl.java:1514)
at oracle.adf.model.dcframe.DataControlFrameImpl.findDataControl(DataControlFrameImpl.java:1474)
at oracle.adf.model.BindingContext.internalFindDataControl(BindingContext.java:1150)
at oracle.adf.model.BindingContext.get(BindingContext.java:1103)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCParameter.evaluateValue(DCParameter.java:82)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCParameter.getValue(DCParameter.java:111)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.getChildByName(DCBindingContainer.java:2743)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalGet(DCBindingContainer.java:2791)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCExecutableBinding.get(DCExecutableBinding.java:115)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCUtil.findSpelObject(DCUtil.java:329)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.evaluateParameterWithElCheck(DCBindingContainer.java:1473)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.findDataControl(DCBindingContainer.java:1603)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.initDataControl(DCIteratorBinding.java:2542)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.getDataControl(DCIteratorBinding.java:2477)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.getAttributeDefs(DCIteratorBinding.java:3319)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlValueBinding.fetchAttrDefs(JUCtrlValueBinding.java:514)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlValueBinding.getAttributeDefs(JUCtrlValueBinding.java:465)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlValueBinding.findAttributeDef(JUCtrlValueBinding.java:616)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlValueBinding.lookupAttributeDef(JUCtrlValueBinding.java:587)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierBinding$1JUCtrlHierHintsMap.internalGet(JUCtrlHierBinding.java:184)
at oracle.jbo.common.JboAbstractMap.get(JboAbstractMap.java:54)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlHierBinding$1DecoratedHintsMap.internalGet(FacesCtrlHierBinding.java:305)
at oracle.jbo.common.JboAbstractMap.get(JboAbstractMap.java:54)
at javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:164)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.bean.FacesBeanImpl.getProperty(FacesBeanImpl.java:73)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.table.BaseColumnRenderer.getProperty(BaseColumnRenderer.java:1195)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.table.BaseColumnRenderer.getSortProperty(BaseColumnRenderer.java:1126)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.table.BaseColumnRenderer.layoutHeader(BaseColumnRenderer.java:634)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.table.BaseColumnRenderer.encodeAll(BaseColumnRenderer.java:152)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1452)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:511)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:923)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1681)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:624)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:3201)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.table.BaseTableRenderer.layoutColumnHeader(BaseTableRenderer.java:1197)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.TableRenderer.encodeAll(TableRenderer.java:636)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1452)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:511)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:923)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCollection.encodeEnd(UIXCollection.java:617)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1681)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:624)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:3201)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DecorativeBoxRenderer.encodeFacet(DecorativeBoxRenderer.java:440)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DecorativeBoxRenderer._encodeCenterPane(DecorativeBoxRenderer.java:711)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DecorativeBoxRenderer.encodeAll(DecorativeBoxRenderer.java:380)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1452)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:511)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:923)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1681)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:624)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:3201)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DecorativeBoxRenderer.encodeFacet(DecorativeBoxRenderer.java:440)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DecorativeBoxRenderer._encodeCenterPane(DecorativeBoxRenderer.java:711)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DecorativeBoxRenderer.encodeAll(DecorativeBoxRenderer.java:380)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1452)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:511)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:923)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1681)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:624)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:3201)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeStretchedChild(RichRenderer.java:2194)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelSplitterRenderer._renderPane(PanelSplitterRenderer.java:1599)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelSplitterRenderer.encodeAll(PanelSplitterRenderer.java:279)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1452)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:511)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:923)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1681)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:624)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:3201)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:641)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAllChildrenInContext(RichRenderer.java:3062)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.FormRenderer.encodeAll(FormRenderer.java:274)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1452)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:511)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:923)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1681)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:624)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:3201)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:641)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAllChildrenInContext(RichRenderer.java:3062)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DocumentRenderer.encodeAll(DocumentRenderer.java:1275)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1452)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:511)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:923)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1681)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1677)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.component.AdfViewRoot.encodeAll(AdfViewRoot.java:91)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:399)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl$ChangeApplyingVDLWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:350)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:273)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:165)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:1035)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:342)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:236)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:509)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:173)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01882: timezone region  not found

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:462)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:405)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:931)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:481)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:205)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:548)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:202)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1110)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1488)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:2147)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:2091)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:320)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.setSessionTimeZone(PhysicalConnection.java:13052)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_T4CConnection.setSessionTimeZone(Unknown Source)
at oracle.jbo.server.OracleSQLBuilderImpl.setSessionTimeZone(OracleSQLBuilderImpl.java:5534)
... 164 more
```

Comment: As you stacktraces already points out:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01882: timezone region not found
What is your DB and ADF version?

Comment: DB 10g and JDeveloper 11g Release 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was updated java, and i found two versions in my laptop (Java 7 update 13, Java 8 update 45), i delete the newer version(Java 8 update 45) and the project started normally.
Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the timezone explicitly to Weblogic server, passing it as argument:

> -Duser.timezone="+06:00"

More info, here:
http://www.baigzeeshan.com/2009/11/ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found.html

Comment: you need to figure out what is the timezone your computer has. Then you need to calculate the difference beetween your computer timezone and UK time zone, for instance